# How can i apply jquery on all elements with same id attribute?

Tags: jquery

How can i apply jquery on all elements with same id attribute ?

i want to apply a `focus()` and `blur()` function on a `textarea` elements that have same id?

Comment: If there is more than one element on a page with the same id that is invalid html.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you should not have more than one element with the same `ID`.

However, you could do this with CSS classes:

```
<div>
 <textarea class="Text"></textarea>
 <textarea class="Text"></textarea>
 <textarea class="Text"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
    $(".Text").focus();
    $(".Text").blur();
</script>
```

Answer (score 26):

The right answer would be

```
$("[id=yourID]").doSomething()
```

for any code like

```
<textarea id="yourID" />
<img id="yourID" />
<div id="yourID" />
```

yes, i know, this is not valid html but note that we middle-class-developers often have to deal with problems "better" developers made.
Check out Microsoft SharePoint for example, where multiple IDs are very common. And we cannot tell our customers that Microsoft did poorly so we cannot help them. We tell them Microsoft did poorly so we have to help them;-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID, you should use classes, then access them like so.

```
$(".classname").focus()
```

And if you want to focus on a single ID use

```
$("#idname").focus()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is best not to use the same id for 2 elements on the same page.  Other forms that sets the textarea nodes can be

```
$('textarea').blur()   // note it sets all textarea elements on the page
```

or

```
$('#content textarea, #comment-area textarea').blur()
```

or if you create a class for these textarea nodes, you can use that too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot/shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. You could use a class selector but I would definitely fix the ids problem first.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have more than one element with the same id not only is it invalid html but if you trageted it using jquery it would only effect the first one. you should use a class

```
$('.class_name').blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple if you want use `$("#yourID").click(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery delegate

syntax

```
jQuery('body').delegate("#your-id","click",function(e){ // do code here });
```